# How I Can Deploy ? - Logic Update In Laravel Back with React Native Mobile Application

Tags: laravel, react-native, deployment, versioning

I have a React Native application in production environment on Android and iOS. I need to make update on specific feature on my Laravel back logic but this change will brake the older versions of the mobile application.

FYI, the change is not on an API route.

Do you know the right way to deploy the new back version without breaking older application version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deploy the version of your mobile application first. The new feature is ready to works but it is disabled. When your update is available on PlayStore and AppStore, you can deploy the new version of backend. Now, the new feature on application will active automatically.

⚠️ On your back do not delete your old logic just create new version of your existing logic because old version of your mobile application will continue to use the old version.